# What do you call a manipulative person?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the most appropriate (single word) noun to describe someone who is manipulative? That is, in the sense of manipulating people in a negative context.

Edit:

In the original discussion from which this question arose, we rejected *manipulator* on the grounds that it felt too much to apply to someone manipulating *objects* rather than *people*. (That is of course, just opinion.)

Comment: A *manipulator*?

Comment: That has the feeling they are manipulating *things* rather than *people*.

Comment: *manipulative* is usually not used in the context of things, where **dextrous** would fit better.

Comment: Anything they want you to.

Comment: A **user**. Yes it has other meanings. Context always helps.

Comment: Are you looking for a word for manipulating objects or events; with a positive or a negative inflection?

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for a single-word NOUN to replace "manipulative person." Didn't @WS2 get it right (at least the noun part) from the start?

Comment: I think this question was asked about a month ago, because I replied "psychopath" then, too.

Comment: (Never mind -- found the thread and it was a different topic.)

Comment: @PapaPoule - OP's reply to WS2 was ambiguous to me, I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: A well-practiced psychopath.

Comment: @δοῦλος's suggestion of 'user' - one who uses other people as a mere means to achieve their own ends, rather than valuing others for their intrinsic worth - is a very good one IMO.

Comment: RE: _That has the feeling they are manipulating things rather than people._ Interesting point; I'd recommend you expand your question a little bit, and explain why you don't like _manipulator_, so that anyone reading this question can figure that out without reading through these comments down here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... most appropriate (single word) noun...

***[Schemer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/schemer)*** offers more negative implications:

> NOUN
>
> A person who is involved in making secret or underhand plans.
>
> *[Vincent Drucci](http://www.myalcaponemuseum.com/id111.htm) became known as The Schemer because of the way played both the police and Al Capone for his own pleasure.*

***[Manager](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manager)*** can imply either positive of negative feelings depending on the perception of the relationship between the manipulator and the manipulated:

> NOUN
>
> 1 A person responsible for controlling or administering an
>   organization or group of staff:

***[Manipulator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manipulator)*** remains the best noun to describe a manipulative person with either connotation:

> NOUN
>
> 1. A person who controls or influences others in a **clever** or **unscrupulous** way.
> 2. A person who handles or controls something **skillfully**.

Answer (score 5):

If the manipulations are selfishly motivated with the goal of getting ahead, then **Machiavellian** fits.

More generally, **artful**. If the manipulations are subtle, then **sly**.

Answer (score 5):

The best single word to describe someone who is manipulative, is **"manipulative"**.

> "a manipulative person tries to control people to their advantage" [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/manipulative)

Other adjectives such as "designing", "artful", "shrewd", etc, won't describe manipulative any better.

Comment: Sometimes the word you want is the word you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

If positive then perhaps, *Facility*: 2. an ability to do or learn something well and easily; a natural aptitude. "he had a facility for languages" *synonyms*: aptitude, talent, gift, flair, bent, skill, knack, genius

I just google.commed this.

Comment: Your interpretation of OPs opinion of 'manipulator' was exactly right. I took it that way too, at least enough to put "(at least the noun part)" in my comment up top. +1 to you and Ulrich for at least getting the noun part right as well.

Comment: Thanks, @PapaPoule, it was a little difficult to figure out *exactly* what the OP wanted, so I just took a shot in the dark. Good to know I hit something!

Answer (score 1):

Somebody who manipulates other people, in particular if they (or the public at large) are not aware of it, is a *puppetmaster*.

([Oxforddictionaries.com suggests it's one word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puppetmaster?q=puppetmaster), personally, I'd have written it as *puppet master*.)