# Word that means using a falsehood which can be used as a weapon to advocate for and execute something else

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means using a falsehood which can be used as a means, as a weapon to advocate for and execute something else

> The politician claimed that the government budget had a deficit to defend cuts in welfare and local services like libraries and nurseries. However this deficit did not exist so the politician was being ______

> Guinness adverts once claimed that guinness is good for you and will help you be alert if you're driving, studying or doing manual labour. This made it marketed as a health drink which then could be an means to sell it in gyms.

> Kyle claimed that his bank account was overdrawn and that he didn't want to receive a daily overdraft fee, which then allowed him to borrow £200 which he otherwise would not of been lent the money if he had been honest about his financial situation. This lie made meant he was ________

Comment: What's a weaponized means?

Comment: I meant weaponised as in taking advantage of "divide and conquer" or people feeling disenfranchised, though weaponised would only apply in the first example.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221831/what-do-you-call-a-manipulative-person?r=SearchResults

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Please check the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to find one word for all the three contexts. I first thought of ***fraudulent***, but the second context does not seem to involve liability to law.

Maybe ***manipulative*** could work:

> tending to influence or control someone or something to your advantage, often without anyone knowing it. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manipulative))

But the -ing form of the verb to manipulate could also be used as an adjective:

***manipulating***

*to manipulate* means

> to control something or someone to your advantage, often unfairly or dishonestly
>
> - The opposition leader accused government ministers of manipulating the statistics to suit themselves. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manipulate))

The politician, the Guinness adverts and Kyle could be said to be manipulative/manipulating.

Answer (score 1):

However this deficit did not exist so the politician was being **Machiavellian**

from [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Machiavellian)

> 2. (adj) being or acting in accordance with the principles of government analyzed in Machiavelli's The Prince, in which political expediency is placed above morality.
> 3. (adj) characterized by unscrupulous cunning, deception, or expediency.

> (noun) - a cunning, amoral, and opportunist person, esp a politician

> [References in literature:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Machiavellian):
>
> - "In fact, moral courage, integrity, steadfastness, self-esteem, etc., are among the major disqualifications to survive in this field, which is a full-time risk-free business that requires **Machiavellian** approach."
> - "This also applies to **Machiavellian** supervisors, who are characterized by behavior that is inherently manipulative and deceitful."

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/pt/dictionary/english/machiavellian)

> If you describe someone as Machiavellian, you are critical of them because they often make clever and secret plans to achieve their aims and are not honest with people.